# hostgator: wildcard subdomain mapping to URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have been struggling with this problem on hostgator shared hosting server for the past 3 hours. This is the problem in the simplest.

This is the mapping i want to happen:
subdomain.domain.com --> www.domain.com/test.php?user=subdomain

but for some reason whenever i enter "subdomain.domain.com" the redirection doesn't happen and even the URL doesn't change in my browser. And I see test.php file listed on loaded page (because The only files i have on server are .htaccess and test.php).

This is the .htacess code

```
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteBase /

            <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).domain.com(.*)$ [NC]
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/test.php?user=$1$2 [P,L]
            </IfModule>

            <IfModule !mod_proxy.c>
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
                    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).domain.com(.*)$ [NC]
                    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/test.php?user=$1$2 [R=301,L]
            </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
```

and this is the test.php code

```
<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>
```

does anyone know what the issue here is? the support was not helpful to me. i think there is something wrong with the server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteCond` backreferences use a percent, not dollar sign! %1 not $1.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+).domain.com(.*)$ [NC]
                          ^ %1                  ^ %2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/test.php?user=$1$2 [R=301,L]
             ^$1                                       ^^^^ oops
```

`$1` means pull something from the regex on the left; %1 means pull it from the `RewriteCond`. You may be sticking the whole match as the user part, assuming the rewriter doesn't choke on the fact that `$2` is a dangling backreference.

Comment: I just tried this but still seeing the same problem. i see this in error log client denied by server configuration: /home/user/public_html/.htaccess

Comment: It's the same problem if the problem is "it doesn't work". Is it failing in exactly the same way before (the changes make absoutely no difference?)

Comment: i found that this is common server error if there is no index.php file when requesting domain.com url. with your suggestion i got it work. thanks.