# dynamic subdomains with htaccess: URL shouldnt change in the browser

Tags: mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

Trying to implement subdomains with htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9]+)\.domain.com(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/index.php?/public_site/main/%1/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

when i enter **ahser.domain.com** the browser URL is changing. is there a htaccess option to not let this happen when absolute URLs is used in RewriteRule?

Comment: I see you are properly getting the matched parts from the `RewriteCond` now with the `%` notation. I spotted that problem in your code, in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632242/hostgator-wildcard-subdomain-mapping-to-url . You used the solution, but did not accept the answer.

Comment: sorry. I am new user. I need at least 15 reputations to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't rewrite to a full URL with domain in it. That generates a redirect since it's going to a different website! You could put `microsoft.com` there; so how would it work without redirecting?

What you have to do is make sure that the web pages work under the original domain. So when the client asks for `myname.domain.com/...` how about rewriting that to `myname.domain.com/index.php?public_site/main/myname/...`. Keep the domain the same.  The `index.php?` can be made to work in any of those domains. For instance, even this could work:

```
http://OTHER.domain.com/index.php?public_site/main/MYNAME/...
```

I.e. set it up so it doesn't matter which virtual host accesses that path.

Once you have that, the rewrite can then just do:

```
# will not trigger redirect
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/public_site/main/%1/$1 [L]
```

You have to be careful not to introduce a loop since you're now redirecting a URL to a longer URL which matches the same rewrite rulethe same domain. You need an additional `RewriteCond` not to apply this rewrite if the URL already starts with `/index.php?public_site/`.

Comment: hmmm... you are right. i understand why the redirect need to work like that.

Comment: hmmm... you are right. i understand why the redirect need to work like that. I wanted simple urls at the user end. so if i am to implement subdomains on my site which give simple urls at the user end i think doing it in the php is better than htaccess.